# "Failed to provision a Cloud Shell", but Azure outages shows operational

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I've been trying to use the Cloud Shell, but it keeps showing "Failed to provision a Cloud Shell" (see graphic below). When I go to the Azure outage page at https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/, it shows that it is still operational. Thoughts on what might be the issue, and/or ways to report this? (As added context, these snapshots were taken within seconds of each other.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can refer to [Troubleshooting known cloud shell issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: You can also open an issue on GitHub: [Microsoft/terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues) or [Azure/azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues)

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a transient issue if not already reported on the [Azure Status page](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/) and normally restores quickly. As a quick troubleshooting step, you could [restart Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/using-the-shell-window#restart-cloud-shell) that would reset machine state and create a new session for you.

[image: Restart Cloud Shell]

If the issue persists, you can file a bug report with the [Azure/azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=Bug_report.md&title=) repository.